# C# - How to avoid Max Connection Pool Error in a loop of SQL commands

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am getting an error message:
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

My code:

```
clsDBConn dbConn = new clsDBConn();
SqlDataCommand CMD;

private void Recompute()
{
   CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", dbConn.connection);
   SqlDataReader EmplReader = CMD.ExecuteReader();
   while (EmplReader.Read())
   {
      while(DateFrom >= DateTo)
      {
         //Some Reader 
         //Lots of SQL Command ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }
}
```

I read some solution about this error. They say i should open and close the connection.
But the problem is if the connection is close i cant access the value of the reader which i need to concatenate in my sqlcommands.

I am looping 50 plus employee and each employee computes time records(Lates, OT, Undertimes, Etc.)

What should I do?

Comment: Is the error command timeout?

I suggest you load your employees on memory. Then do the loop for each employee for processing.

Comment: Wrap any use of `SqlClient` objects that implement `IDisposable` in `using` statements. (In fact, that advice applies to most `IDisposable`s, not just the SQL ones)

Comment: you should dispose resources like - try using

Comment: Is this Recompute method called inside a loop? If not then the problem is elsewhere (still caused by the fact that you don't dispose the connections created in the clsDBConn when done with them)

Comment: Probably you should add the code of the class clsDBConn (in particular its constructor and its connection property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dispose your connection by the using the `using` keyword, and you can also try to increase the timeout about by adding the `CommandTimeout`

```
private void Recompute()
{
    using(clsDBConn dbConn = new clsDBConn())
    {
        SqlDataCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", dbConn.connection);
        CMD.CommandTimeout = 120;
        using(SqlDataReader EmplReader = CMD.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (EmplReader.Read())
            {
                while(DateFrom >= DateTo)
                {
                    //Some Reader 
                    //Lots of SQL Command ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Also your clsDBConn must implement the IDisposable interface and Define the Dispose() method,

```
public class clsDBConn : IDisposable
    {
        private bool disposedValue = false; 

        ....
        ....
        ....

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
                }

                disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

**Second Option :** you have another option (which I don't prefer to use but still works) if your clsDBConn has the .Close() method you can simply use it like this :

```
private void Recompute()
{
    clsDBConn dbConn = new clsDBConn();
    SqlDataCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", dbConn.connection);
    CMD.CommandTimeout = 120;
    using(SqlDataReader EmplReader = CMD.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (EmplReader.Read())
        {
            while(DateFrom >= DateTo)
            {
                //Some Reader 
                //Lots of SQL Command ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    dbConn.Close();
}
```

The small difference between .Close() and .Dispose(), is that with .Close() you can open the connection again without having to create a second instance of clsDBConn.

Comment: How do you know if the class clsDBConn implements the IDisposable  interface required to use the using statement around its instances?

Comment: I assumed that it is already done, otherwise he should just use the .Close() method

Comment: @Steve i am getting an error "type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'"

Comment: in which line ? your clsDBConn must implements the IDisposable and define the .Dispose() method inside your clsDBConn. Same thing about the SqlDataCommand class, I will edit my answer to add that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `Dispose` of your connections in order to return them to the pool. Just execute `dbConn.connection.Dispose()` when you are done with you class instance. Or move the creation of connection to your method and use `using`:

```
using(var dbConn = new clsDBConn())
{
   using(var CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", dbConn.connection))
   {
      using(SqlDataReader EmplReader = CMD.ExecuteReader())
      {
         while (EmplReader.Read())
         {
            while(DateFrom >= DateTo)
            {
            //Some Reader 
            //Lots of SQL Command ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that your class `clsDBConn` needs to implement `IDisposable` and execute `connection.Dispose()` as its implementation in order for this to work.

Comment: The command and the reader ought also to be dealt with in the same way.

Comment: how to implement IDisposable? I am getting an error  "type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'"